Is there any way to get all the Action names present in a Try block in Logic Apps
Is there any way to retrieve the action names within the try block? I need to obtain these action names and create a string with them separated by commas. How can I achieve this?
Tried the below but not working
@actions('Try').actions


You need at least 2 actions for this.
Firstly, you need to use the Select action to get the names of the actions within the "Try" block as an array:

You should be selecting @item()?['name'] from @result('Try').

Secondly, you need to transform the array to a comma-separated string. You can use the join function for this: @join(body('Select'), ',')



If your aim is to list all previous actions (and extract the result), try this code in your catch block:
result('Try')

The result() function returns the results from the top-level actions in the specified scoped action. This also contains the names of the actions.
